# Eliminate duplicates in R

Tags: r

If I have a df like this

```
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,3,4),n=c("x","y","e","w"))
data
  id n
1  1 x
2  1 y
3  3 e
4  4 w
```

I want to get a new df like this:

```
data
  id n
3  3 e
4  4 w
```

That is, I want it to remove all repeating rows. I've tried functions like `distinct` from `dplyr` but it always gets one of the repeating rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another `subset` option with `ave`

```
subset(
    data,
    ave(n, id, FUN = length) == 1
)
```

gives

```
  id n
3  3 e
4  4 w
```

Answer (score 3):

We may need `duplicated`

```
subset(data, !(duplicated(id)|duplicated(id, fromLast = TRUE)))
  id n
3  3 e
4  4 w
```

---

or use `table`

```
subset(data, id %in% names(which(table(id) == 1)))
  id n
3  3 e
4  4 w
```

Answer (score 1):

Although more verbose, you can also use base R.

```
data[!(duplicated(data["id"])|duplicated(data["id"], fromLast=TRUE)),]
```

Output

```
  id n
3  3 e
4  4 w
```

Or use `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
    dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
    dplyr::filter(n() == 1) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the already useful answers with a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% filter(
        !(duplicated(id,fromLast = FALSE) | duplicated(id,fromLast = TRUE) )
)
```

`distinct` won't work for you, as it will retain **all** distinct values based on, in your case, `id` in which 1 is always a part of.